# Where can I ask for payments module documentation?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I am trying to setup my own merchant-plugin-interface for our payments module but can't find any source which can give me request/response formats for vareq/vares/pareq etc. api calls. I suppose these requests have a fixed format but can't find it anywhere?

What is the correct Stack Exchange site to ask this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't one here. Asking for links to documentation is basically asking for us to be your search engine proxy, such information even if we could find it leads to answers that are not self contained and therefore rot. They also end up as spam magnets.

If you know what the API is and how it should work and it's something that does have published documentation then we could help figure out why your particular implementation doesn't work if you showed us the code on Stack Overflow but that's probably the only way you'd get a viable question here.